# Combining Histogram and SmoothHistogram

Tags: graphics, histograms

How can we draw `Histogram` and `SmoothHistogram` together for two data sets?. I'd like to show the first data set using `Histogram`, and the second using `SmoothHistogram`.

Comment: Where is this "data set" you speak of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], 100];

Show[
     Histogram[data1, Automatic, "PDF"],
     SmoothHistogram[data2],
     PlotRange -> All
     ]
```

[image: histogram and smooth histogram]

The important bits are:

- using `"PDF"` for the histogram to match the smooth histogram in height (otherwise the histogram will show counts, and completely dwarf the other plot).
- using `Show` with `PlotRange -> All` to combine the plots, and make sure each part is shown completely.