# Scale SmoothHistogram curve to Histogram

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

Like in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/combining-histogram-and-smoothhistogram), I would like to display a histogram and a smooth histogram in the same plot.

> [image]

I believe the default “bin height specification” (or $\textit{hspec}$) for `Histogram` is `"Count"`, and the default “distribution function” (or $\textit{dfun}$) for `SmoothHistogram` is `"PDF"`.

> [Documentation for `Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html#DetailsAndOptions)
>
> [image]
>
> [Documentation for `SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html#DetailsAndOptions)
>
> [image]

However, I can’t find an analog for `"Count"` in `SmoothHistogram`. There was a suggestion to use `"Intensity"`, but it doesn’t scale the curve correctly:

> [image]

What is the best way to scale the `SmoothHistogram` curve up to the height of the `Histogram` bars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to, you can scale up from the "PDF".  The "scaling" factor depends on how the Histogram was binned, but we can use [`HistogramDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramDistribution.html) to easily get this information (there might even be a much easier way):

```
δ = Length[foo]/(HistogramDistribution[foo]["PDFValues"] // Total)
(* 150. *)
```

and then the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option

```
Show[Histogram[foo], 
 SmoothHistogram[foo, Automatic, "PDF", 
  ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, {#*δ &, #/δ &}}]]
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to make the `Histogram` look like the `SmoothHistogram` as in

```
Show[Histogram[foo, Automatic, "PDF"], SmoothHistogram[foo]]
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: This doesn’t answer my specific question of how to scale _up_ the `SmoothHistogram`. The linked question at the top of my post already instructs how to scale the `Histogram` _down_ using `"PDF"`.

Comment: Understood.  I'm curious as to why you want to go in that direction.  Usually it is the unknown probability density which is the target so going back towards a histogram is not recommended.  In addition, the smooth histogram usually is something to replace the histogram rather than displaying both (other than for the purpose of checking that things worked properly).